# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT] with Android Studio 0.8.1

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to debug my app I am getting this error: **Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]**

I am using Android Studio 0.8.1.
This is the log when I am trying to install and debug the app.

```
Installing <mypackage>
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/<mypackage>"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/<mypackage>
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

Now it happens with all apps in my IDE, with all my real and virtual devices.

Logcat:

```
07-09 01:34:53.895      585-609/? I/PackageManager﹕ Running dexopt on: mypackage
07-09 01:34:53.915  17728-17728/? W/dalvikvm﹕ DexOptZ: zip archive '/data/app/mypackage-1.apk' does not include classes.dex
07-09 01:34:53.915      177-177/? W/installd﹕ DexInv: --- END '/data/app/mypackage-1.apk' --- status=0xff00, process failed
07-09 01:34:53.915      177-177/? E/installd﹕ dexopt in='/data/app/mypackage.apk' out='/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@mypackage-1.apk@classes.dex' res=65280
07-09 01:34:53.915      585-609/? W/PackageManager﹕ Couldn't delete native library directory /data/app-lib/mypackage
```

Comment: There should be something in logcat with more info about what's failing

Comment: As per the log, the apk would seem to be incorrectly built (?)

Comment: @matiash Yes, the apk doesn't contain classes.dex, but I don't know the reason. Gradle seems to build it without errors.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Never seen this before. Could you run `gradlew clean` and then post the output of `gradlew build`?

Comment: @matiash the output of `gradlew build` is correct (when it builds the classes.dex isn't UP-TO-DATE, so it should build it). Hovewer the apk doesn't contain it. 
I am going to clean the cache and reset the `.AndroidStudioBeta` folder.

Comment: Solved invalidating the cache and deleting the `.AndroidStudioBeta` folder.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti You can post what works for you as an answer and accept it. It may be beneficial for others as well...

Comment: Not working for me. This is driving me mad.

Comment: I also get this error in Run tab when I am trying to install a new version (changed a strin name) to the emulator. Three hours earlier I had a SDK Tools update to 23.0.5

Comment: ok, deleting .AndroidStudioBeta worked for me!

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti how did you invalidate the cache?

Comment: Also, the .AndroidStudioBeta keeps reappearing even after I delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved invalidating the cache and deleting the `.AndroidStudioBeta` folder

To invalidate the cache use in Android Studio: `File -> Invalidate Caches and restart`

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error appeared  when i enabled again Instant Run. By disabling it dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I have done the following steps to fix it

1. Android studio -> Build -> Clean Project
2. Android studio -> Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: This sometimes works for me too, but after 3 or 4 build iterations the problem appears again. Have not found a solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use ProGuard to optimize your code.